# CSS border-image gradient on one side?

Tags: css

The following CSS produces a gradient border on the left & right side of an element:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-left: 10px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(#00f,#000) 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5p8cv5t9/

How can I apply the gradient only to the left side?

Comment: You can add `border-right: 0;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define no border width on all other sides easily. The issue stems from the fact that the default [border-width (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width) value is `medium`, not `0`.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-width: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(#00f, #000) 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I looked everywhere for this, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

you can define right border to 0px. Hope this helps.

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 10px solid;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(#00f,#000) 0 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-left: 10px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(#00f,#000) 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).